# EaselJS CreateJS 'pressmove', 'pressup' not working

Tags: mousemove, easeljs, createjs

I've converted a .fla file to .js file, I've added several listeners on multiple elements in that file. Among which 'click','mousedown' & 'mouseover' are working fine, but 'pressmove' & 'pressup' events are not responding, and they are not even generating any error. Here is my code snippet:

```
/****this snippet is from converted .js file *********/

(lib.knob_rot_but = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 2
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f().s("#999999").ss(0.5,1,1).p("ABlhlQArArAAA6QAAA7grAqQgqArg7AAQg6AAgrgrQgqgqAAg7QAAg6AqgrQArgqA6AAQA7AAAqAqg");
    this.shape.setTransform(26.4,0);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.rf(["#FFFFFF","#CCCCCC","#999999","#666666"],[0.239,0.8,0.941,1],-0.2,0.2,0,-0.2,0.2,14.8).s().p("AhlBlQgqgqAAg7QAAg6AqgqQArgqA6gBQA7ABAqAqQAqAqAAA6QAAA7gqAqQgqAqg7AAQg6AAgrgqg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(26.4,0);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]}).wait(4));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();

/******* My Listeners ******/
var helpButtonDown = DeviceService.getHelpButtonDown();
helpButtonDown.addEventListener("click", function(){alert("helpButtonDown button clicked")});  //works fine

var powerButtonUp = DeviceService.getPowerButtonUp();
powerButtonUp.addEventListener("click", function(){alert("powerButtonUp clicked")});//works fine


/*** Knob Listener***/
var knob = DeviceService.getKnob();
knob.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){console.log("mousedown on knob")}); //woks fine
knob.addEventListener("pressmove", function(evt){console.log("proess move on knob evt :" + evt)}); // doesn't work :(
```

Comment: Changeing to V0.7.0 worked for me. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 5):

Touch events such as **pressmove** and **pressup** require you to enable the Touch Class, see the example and Docs below.

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvasId");
createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
```

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Touch.html

Comment: Touch events require this, pressmove will still work using the mouse without

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. My script started working after adding this!

Answer (score 2):

The events **pressmove** and **pressup** were introduced in version v0.7.0 whereas the CreateJS publisher publishes to v0.6.0. Try changing to version v0.7.0 in your tag.